# Disabling <select> option based on other <select> option

Tags: jquery

How to disable multiple options in select, in case that exact options are selected in other selects. I found answered question for problem similar to mine on this link:
http://jsfiddle.net/dZqEu/

jQuery code looks next:

```
$(this).siblings('select').children('option').each(function() {
    if ( $(this).val() === value ) {
        $(this).attr('disabled', true).siblings().removeAttr('disabled');   
    }
```

The problem is that this works only for 2 selects. I need total 3 selects which should disable possibility that same values in selects are selected.

This code won't work for 3 selects:
http://jsfiddle.net/dZqEu/968/

Tnx in advance

NOTE:

When the select1 is set to 1, select 2 is set to 2, i can't disable values 1&2 in select3. It only disables value 2 in select 3...

Comment: Your code is disabling the value selected across all selects, *for* all selects. What exactly is your problem?

Comment: look at the example with 3 selects. when the select1 is set to 1, select 2 is set to 2, i can't disable values 1&2 in select3. It only disables value 2 in select 3...

Comment: You should probably enable jQuery in your fiddle.

Comment: +1 just for the 968th update on same fiddle.

Comment: Isn't this what you want -- http://jsfiddle.net/QLn9b/1/

Comment: @tymeJV Chose Type 1, 2 and 3 resp. for three selects. Change first to 'No match' and try to change the middle one.

Comment: @hjpotter92 i didn't saw this coming...

Comment: code should remove attribute disabled, when it is not selected anymore...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try this:- http://jsfiddle.net/Z2yaG/

Using focus to get the prev value and remove disabled ones.
In your html i have added value -1 for default option.

```
<option value="-1">No Match</option>

     var prev = -1;
$("select").change(function () {
    if ($(this).val() > -1) {
        $("select").not(this).find("option[value=" + $(this).val() + "]").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    }
    $("select").not(this).find("option[value=" + previous + "]").removeAttr('disabled');
}).focus(function () {
    previous = $(this).val();
});
```

Comment: Updated fiddle link with jquery1.4.4... Thanks for pointing out.. I dint notice.

Comment: Disclaimer: i improved on @tymejv answer

Comment: Dunno what I did to reach here; but well there is still some bug: http://i.imgur.com/Z78WL3F.png

Comment: @hjpotter92 i got the issue, updated the answer and fiddle. Check this.

Comment: Glad it helped, also i believe @tymeJV deserves a vote as this is improved from his approach..:)

Comment: yes of course, all of you deserve vote up, everybody helped in a way :)

Answer (score 2):

This seems to work: http://jsfiddle.net/QLn9b/1/

It is using your original code:

```
$("select").change(function() {   
    $("select").not(this).find("option[value="+ $(this).val() + "]").attr('disabled', true);
});
```

Comment: this is what I need, but code should remove attribute disabled, when it is not selected anymore...

Comment: Nice finishing it up! Got too wrapped up in other stuff today to come back to it :\

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you are looking for.

```
$('select').change(function() {

  var select_elements = $('select')
  $.each(select_elements, function(i,elem){
    var sel_values = [];

    // Selecting and Iterating on Sibling Selects        
    var siblis = $(elem).siblings('select')
    $.each(siblis, function(i, sibli){
        if($(sibli).val()!='No Match'){
            sel_values.push($(sibli).val());
        }
    });

    // Iterating on Options of Select
    $(this).children('option').each(function() {
        $(this).removeAttr('disabled');

        if($.inArray($(this).val(), sel_values) !== -1){
            $(this).attr('disabled', true);
        }
    });        

  });    
});
```

If All selects has the values from 1 to 6,

```
If select1 value      --> 1,
and select2 value     --> 3 (1 is disabled)
then in select3 value --> 5 (1,3 are disabled)
```

After selecting select3,

```
In select1  --> 1 (3,5 disabled)
In select2  --> 3 (1,5 disabled)
In select3  --> 5 (1,3 disabled)
```

Here is the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/prem_nagalla1/rY4n3/

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 1):

This is one way. When any dropdown changes, calculate all selected values (except the first one). If the selected value of the other boxes occurs in the list of values, disable the respective option.

```
$('select').change(function() {
    var values = [],
    others = $(this).siblings('select'),
    all = others.andSelf();

    all.each(function() {
        if (this.selectedIndex > 0) {
            values.push(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value);
        }
    });

    others.each(function() {
        for (var i = 0; i < this.options.length; ++i) {
            this.options[i].disabled = $.inArray(this.options[i].value, values) !== -1;
        }
    });
});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/dZqEu/999/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
$('select').change(function() 
{    
    var value = $(this).val();
    $('option').removeAttr("disabled");
    $('select').each(function ()
    {
        $("option[value=" + $(this).val() + "]").attr("disabled","disabled");
    });
});
```