# JQuery Adding new Row in Table based on Selection

Tags: jquery, laravel

When the user selects a value from drop down which is the product a row is dynamically added which work perfectly fine in my laravel project.

Then adding a new product to the row which also adds a row to the Table but the previous product record is also replaced by this product value.

```
    <div class="card-body">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 form-group table-responsive m-b-30">
                <table class="table table-bordered" id="trainingsTable">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Ekle</th>
                        <th>Eğitim</th>
                        <th>Satış</th>
                        <th>Liste</th>
                        <th>İndirimli</th>
                        <th>Sınav</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td><button type="button" name="add" id="add" class="btn btn-success"><i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i></button></td>
                        <td>
                            <select class="form-control selectTraining" name="training_id[]" id="training_id[]">
                                <option>Seçiniz</option>
                                @foreach($trainings as $training)
                                <option data-price="{{ $training->price }}" data-listprice="{{ $training->list_price }}" data-examprice="{{ $training->exam_price }}" value="{{ $training->id }}">{{ $training->name }}</option>
                                @endforeach
                            </select>
                        </td>
                        <td>{!! Form::text('sale_amount[]', old('sale_amount'), ['id' => 'sale_amount[]', 'class' => 'form-control sale_amount']) !!}</td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="list_price" id="list_price" value="" class="form-control list_price" disabled /></td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="price" id="price" value="" class="form-control price" disabled /></td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="exam_price" id="exam_price" value="" class="form-control exam_price" disabled /></td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
                </table> 
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

// Script Start
    $('.selectTraining').on('change', function() {
        $('.list_price').val($(this).find(':selected').data('listprice'));
        $('.price').val($(this).find(':selected').data('price'));
        $('.exam_price').val($(this).find(':selected').data('examprice'));
    });
    var i = 0;
    $("#add").click(function(){
        ++i;
        $("#trainingsTable").append('<tr>' +
            '<td><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger remove-tr"><i class="fa fa-minus-circle"></i></button></td>' +
            '<td>' +
                '<select class="form-control selectTraining" name="training_id[]" id="training_id[]">' +
                    '<option>Seçiniz</option>' +
                    '@foreach($trainings as $training)' +
                    '<option data-price="{{ $training->price }}" data-listprice="{{ $training->list_price }}" data-examprice="{{ $training->exam_price }}" value="{{ $training->id }}" >{{ $training->name }}</option>' +
                    '@endforeach' +
                '</select>' +
            '</td>' +
            '<td>{!! Form::text('sale_amount[]', old('sale_amount'), ['id' => 'sale_amount[]', 'class' => 'form-control sale_amount']) !!}</td>' +
            '<td><input type="text" name="list_price" id="list_price" value="" class="form-control list_price" disabled /></td>' +
            '<td><input type="text" name="price" id="price" value="" class="form-control price" disabled /></td>' +
            '<td><input type="text" name="exam_price" id="exam_price" value="" class="form-control exam_price" disabled /></td></tr>');
            $('.selectTraining').on('change', function() {
                $('.list_price').val($(this).find(':selected').data('listprice'));
                $('.price').val($(this).find(':selected').data('price'));
                $('.exam_price').val($(this).find(':selected').data('examprice'));
            });
    });
    $(document).on('click', '.remove-tr', function(){  
            $(this).parents('tr').remove();
    });
// Script End
```

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OAE3F.jpg)

A product can be selected in the sold row and the offer Price, Discounted Price and Exam Fee are automatically filled in the relevant fields. But when two or more lines are selected, all fields are filled with the latest contact information, crushing other selections.

Thanks for helps...

Comment: Your question is not clear. Add more code to your question such as your javascript code, Laravel code, etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When your select-box changes you are targetting all inputs with class `list_price , price..etc` .Instead you can use `$(this).closest('tr')` this will get the closest  tr where select-box has been change then use `.find()` to find inputs and add required values there .

***Demo Code*** :

```js
$(document).on('change', '.selectTraining', function() {
  var selector = $(this).closest('tr') //get closest tr
  //find inputs inside required tr and then find input
  selector.find('.list_price').val($(this).find(':selected').data('listprice'));
  selector.find('.price').val($(this).find(':selected').data('price'));
  selector.find('.exam_price').val($(this).find(':selected').data('examprice'));
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.2/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-HK5fgLBL+xu6dm/Ii3z4xhlSUyZgTT9tuc/hSrtw6uzJOvgRr2a9jyxxT1ely+B+xFAmJKVSTbpM/CuL7qxO8w==" crossorigin="anonymous" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="card-body">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 form-group table-responsive m-b-30">
      <table class="table table-bordered" id="trainingsTable">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Ekle</th>
            <th>Eğitim</th>
            <th>Satış</th>
            <th>Liste</th>
            <th>İndirimli</th>
            <th>Sınav</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td><button type="button" name="add" id="add" class="btn btn-success"><i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i></button></td>
            <td>
              <select class="form-control selectTraining" name="training_id[]" id="training_id[]">
                <option>Seçiniz</option>

                <option data-price="12" data-listprice="23" data-examprice="32" value="1">A</option>
                <option data-price="13" data-listprice="33" data-examprice="33" value="2">B</option>
              </select>
            </td>
            <td><input type="text" class="form-control sale_amount" name="sale_amount[]">
              <td><input type="text" name="list_price" value="" class="form-control list_price" disabled /></td>
              <td><input type="text" name="price" value="" class="form-control price" disabled /></td>
              <td><input type="text" name="exam_price" value="" class="form-control exam_price" disabled /></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger remove-tr"><i class="fa fa-minus-circle"></i></button></td>
            <td>
              <select class="form-control selectTraining" name="training_id[]" id="training_id[]">
                <option>Seçiniz</option>

                <option data-price="12" data-listprice="23" data-examprice="32" value="1">A</option>
                <option data-price="13" data-listprice="33" data-examprice="33" value="2">B</option>
              </select>
            </td>
            <td><input type="text" class="form-control sale_amount" name="sale_amount[]">
              <td><input type="text" name="list_price" value="" class="form-control list_price" disabled /></td>
              <td><input type="text" name="price" value="" class="form-control price" disabled /></td>
              <td><input type="text" name="exam_price" value="" class="form-control exam_price" disabled /></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger remove-tr"><i class="fa fa-minus-circle"></i></button></td>
            <td>
              <select class="form-control selectTraining" name="training_id[]" id="training_id[]">
                <option>Seçiniz</option>

                <option data-price="12" data-listprice="23" data-examprice="32" value="1">A</option>
                <option data-price="13" data-listprice="33" data-examprice="33" value="2">B</option>
              </select>
            </td>
            <td><input type="text" class="form-control sale_amount" name="sale_amount[]">
              <td><input type="text" name="list_price" value="" class="form-control list_price" disabled /></td>
              <td><input type="text" name="price" value="" class="form-control price" disabled /></td>
              <td><input type="text" name="exam_price" value="" class="form-control exam_price" disabled /></td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you soo much... How can I prevent a selected value from being selected again on the next line?

Comment: Hi, you can disable that option from other select-box  using each loop . Try at your end let me know if that doesn't work.

Comment: I couldn't. Can you help me? 
I need to add to the code above

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16220296/disabling-select-option-based-on-other-select-option) should be helpful .

Comment: did you tried implementing that code in yours ?

Comment: Yes but its not working <script async src="//jsfiddle.net/ZATRANO/wzgqt13f/1/embed/js/"></script>

Comment: link is not correct which you have added in previous comment

Comment: jsfiddle.net/ZATRANO/wzgqt13f/1

Comment: Hi, [this](http://jsfiddle.net/zp5uaLn6/)  should work .

Comment: İts ok thanks but when click add new row all option enable again :(

Comment: Then try like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/3xdapgo0/) and only line you need to add when you append new data is `check_now()`  this function will disable option from newly added select as well. here `$("#add").click(function(){..` add that line in last inside that handler.